# jQuery: do after complete animate doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, hide, jquery-animate

```
$comment.animate({width: 0}, {queue:false, duration:450 }, function() { 
//$comment.css({ 'display': 'block' })
$comment.hide();
 });
```

it doesn't show animation. i guess that i have put a function is wrong place.

Comment: If you are hiding it after `.animate()`, then perhaps it should not show...

Comment: i found answer by TJ Crowder. i need to put "complete: " before function().

Comment: @user453089: Yes, I was just commenting on your explanation, I would imagine the intent of the callback would be to make it not show after the animation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), if you specify options, include the callback *in* the options rather than separately:

```
$comment.animate({width: 0}, {
    queue:    false,
    duration: 450,
    complete: function() { 
        //$comment.css({ 'display': 'block' })
        $comment.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: its been a while, but there's two ways to run a function on completion: either by options like above or with this signature: `animate( { options } , speed , function() { } );`